# Spring Boot still outputs colour even with spring.output.ansi.enabled=NEVER

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to disable colour in the Spring Boot output completely as the logs are going to be viewed as plaintext, not in a terminal.

If I pass in `--spring.output.ansi.enabled=NEVER` as a command line argument it disables some colour such as the text saying Spring Boot, but the logs immediately after are as colourful as always. How can I disable all colour entirely?

Comment: Do you have a separate `logback.xml` config file?

Comment: Yes I do! And it mentions colours. I guess this is the problem.

Comment: Yes it is your issue.

Comment: Were you able to make it work @JPerson ?

Answer (score 1):

I had simular issue with `logback.xml`. Resolved it by setting withJansi to false and removing colors from pattern. Like this:

```
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <withJansi>false</withJansi>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```